# Linking MBCS and Unicode libraries together

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a library written in ISO C++. It doesn't use Winapi, TCHAR or anything like that. I'm currently building it as a static library with character set set to Unicode. I intend to link it to other libraries, some of them built using Unicode, some - MBCS.

Do I need to create two configurations and build two versions (MBCS and Unicode) in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem.  Code that uses utf-16 encoded Unicode strings uses wchar_t*, code that uses a legacy 8-bit encoding uses char*.  Unambiguous both to the compiler and linker.  The only reason the setting exists is because Windows headers and the non-standard `<tchar.h>` contain macros that translate a typedef (like TCHAR) to either of those strings types, guided by the UNICODE and _UNICODE #defines.

Of course, using this library from a program that uses char* for strings will be an enormous pita.  The program must translate the strings, note that a cast won't do.

Comment: All mixes are a pain. Going from Unicode to MBCS, you may not be able to translate some strings at all

Comment: This is more technical question. For example, I learned the hard way that I can't link together libraries built with different versions of Visual Studio and libraries built with static runtime (/MT) with libraries built with dynamic runtime (/MD). I just have a feeling that linker is going to throw a hissy fit even in this case. In my own library text handling is usually templated because we now have 4 character types (char, wchar_t, char16_t and char32_t) and standard library provides necessary traits for all of them).

Comment: Well sure, but that's not what you asked.  Stop having "a feeling" and actually try it so you *know*.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, sorry. I'm definitely going to test this when I get a chance.

Comment: And yes, I've just created a new empty library with just one function to test. I was able to link this library in MBCS mode to Unicode app and vice versa. No linker errors.